# Using javascript regex to replace a character entity

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, entity

I have a set of notes which aren't displaying properly. Looking at the source, there is `&#xd;&#xa;` where the line breaks should be. I want to replace these instances with `<br>`. I've used a bookmarklet which will work for a plaintext string such as `ABC` but it won't work for the given string.

For example, this one works fine:

`javascript:(function(){var re = new RegExp("ABC", "g"); document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML=document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML.replace(re, "<br>" );})();`

Whereas this doesn't:

`javascript:(function(){var re = new RegExp("&#xd;&#xa;", "g"); document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML=document.getElementById('my_span').innerHTML.replace(re, "<br>" );})();`

Oddly the latter will take the first instance of `&#xd;&#xa;` and just remove it without replacing it.

The page I'm working with does not load jQuery and I'm working in a corporate environment so I'm loathe to call something external.

Is this to do with with `innerHTML` not receiving the `&#xd;&#xa;` as I expect it to? Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly like you said: `innerHTML` is not receiving those characters as you expect it to. Inserting character entities into HTML causes them to be interpreted, and `innerHTML` returns the interpreted version, not the raw version. If you have:

```
<p id="test">Cookies &amp; Cream</p>
```

and you use:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
```

you don't get:

```
Cookies &amp; Cream
```

you get:

```
Cookies & Cream
```

Similarly, when you're using `innerHTML` in your bookmarklet, you're not getting `&#xd;&#xa;`: you're getting a carriage return and a line feed.

To match those characters with regex, use `\r\n`. `\r` will match the carriage return (`&#xd;`). While `\n` will match the line feed (`&xa;`).

```
var regex = new RegExp('\r\n', 'g');
```

Comment: Yes that worked a charm on Chrome, thanks. However I come into the office and it fails - pulling the innerHTML in the console shows me that there is in fact nothing there where the line breaks are in the source. IE11. The javascript extends the space between the `tr` elements in the `span`. I know `tr` is read only in IE but I can change the `span`. Frustrating! Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a `<span>` element inside of a `<table>`? That shouldn't be possible. Both Chrome and IE11 should take the `<span>` element out of the table, and place it before the table in the DOM. If the browser is rearranging the DOM, your sequence might be outside of the element with `id="my_span"`. Try `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, '<h1>Hello</h1>');` That will show you if the sequence you're trying to match is where you expect it to be.

Comment: Ah no the `table` is inside the  `span`. Any other string can be replaced but the problem is that there's nothing in the `innerHTML` where the breaks should be. Opened the console and pulled it to see what I'm getting. Odd given that there are the instances of `&#xd;&#xa;` in the source (within each `td`). Happily ditching IE soon. Out of my depth here - IT are dragging their heels and I want to make a temporary fix.

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for. It sounds kind of like you want to extend to space between the rows in a table? If so, there's an easy way to do that: `var table = document.getElementById('id_of_table'); table.style.borderCollapse = 'separate'; table.style.borderSpacing = '0 10px';` If the table doesn't have an ID, you can select it via: `var table = document.querySelector('#my_span table');`. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mnmor57/1/).